# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte in django, Cyrillic problem

Tags: python, django, json

У меня есть база данных с продуктами. Когда я создаю dump файл формата JSON с помощю команды **manage.py dumpdata products.Product > product.json** и если в этом файле есть кириллица, после создания он выгядит следующим образом

```
[
  {
    "model": "products.product",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "╒єфш ўхЁэюую ЎтхЄр ё ьюэюуЁрььрьш adidas Originals",
      "image": "products_images/Adidas-hoodie.png",
      "description": "",
      "short_description": "╠ уър  Єърэ№ фы  ётшЄ°юЄют. ╤Єшы№ ш ъюьЇюЁЄ Ц ¤Єю юсЁрч цшчэш.",
      "price": "6090.00",
      "quantity": 15,
      "categoty": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "products.product",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "name": "╤шэ   ъєЁЄър The North Face",
      "image": "products_images/Blue-jacket-The-North-Face.png",
      "description": "",
      "short_description": "├ырфър  Єърэ№. ┬юфюэхяЁюэшЎрхьюх яюъЁ√Єшх. ╦хуъшщ ш Єхяы√щ яєїют",
      "price": "23725.00",
      "quantity": 7,
      "categoty": 1
    }
  }
]
```

как это исправить, чтоб в следующий раз все сохранилось как надо?